# Pandoc - changing the layout when compiling markdown

Tags: margins, pandoc, markdown

I use `pandoc` to simply compile pdf files from markdown files:

```
pandoc markdown.md -o output.pdf
```

however this renders the PDF with lots of white space. Is there a way to change the layout of the output or do I have to go the way through a `tex` file?

like:

```
pandoc markdown.md -o output.tex

# edit margins of the output.tex;
# then:

pandoc markdown.tex -o output.pdf
```

Comment: You can set the margins with `geometry` in the YAML block, as documented in the manual: https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#variables-for-latex

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As documented in the [pandoc manual](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html), you can either specify the margin in the YAML header of your markdown file:

```
---
geometry: margin=30mm
...
```

Or you can pass the value as a variable on the command line:

```
pandoc markdown.md -V geometry:margin=1in -o output.tex
```